# Simplifying square of partial sums to sum of squares and products

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials, sums-of-squares

Assume the square of sum of $S$ of $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_N$ means the square of the sum of all possible combinations of $S$ values among $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_N$, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{{N \choose S}} (\sum_j v_j)^2
$$
where the inner sum has $S$ values.

**My try**

This sum can be written as the following:
$$
\alpha(v_1^2+\dots+ v_N^2)+\beta(v_1v_2+\dots+v_{N-1}v_N).
$$

**Question**

Is there an intuitive way of finding $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: If you let all $v_i=1$, then the upper sum is $S^2\binom{N}{S}$ and the lower sum is $$\begin{split}N\left(N-S+S\binom{N}{S}\right)+\binom{N}{2}\cdot2S\binom{N}{S}&=N^2-NS+NS\binom{N}{S}+N(N-1)S\binom{N}{S}\\&=N^2-NS+N^2S\binom{N}{S},\end{split}$$ which does not seem to be the same as $S^2\binom{N}{S}$. Just let $S=1$, then the upper expression is $N$ and the lower expression is $(2N-1)N$.

Comment: @Alexander Burstein: Maybe I was wrong. I edited my question.

Comment: Do you mean the following? $$\sum_{A\subset \{1,\dots,N\}: |A|=S} \left(\sum_{j\in A} v_j\right)^2$$

Comment: The square $v_1^2$ occurs whenever a set contains $1$ and $S-1$ arbitrary elements. Therefore, $\alpha=\binom{N-1}{S-1}$. The product $v_1v_2$ occurs twice in every sum over a set of $S$ elements containing $v_1$ and $v_2$. The other $S-2$ elements out of $N-2$ are arbitrary, so $\beta=2\binom{N-2}{S-2}$. And indeed, you can check that the number of terms in the sum is $$\alpha N+\beta\binom{N}{2}=N\binom{N-1}{S-1}+N(N-1)\binom{N-2}{S-2}=(S+S(S-1))\binom{N}{S}=S^2\binom{N}{S},$$ as expected.

Comment: @RobPratt: exactly.

Comment: @Alexander Burstein: Can you please add a little bit explanation to your comment and post it as a solution. Also, would it be possible to convert $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to write them as terms including $N \choose S$? The reason I am asking is I want to know how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend on $N \choose S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I am expanding my comment into an answer. This is a symmetric polynomial, so it is enough to find out how many times $v_1^2$ and $v_1v_2$ occur in the sum.

The square $v_1^2$ occurs whenever a set contains $1$ and $S−1$ arbitrary other elements in $\{2,\dots, N\}$. Therefore, $$\alpha=\binom{N-1}{S-1}=\frac{S}{N}\binom{N}{S}.$$ The product $v_1v_2$ occurs twice in every sum over a set of $S$ elements containing $v_1$ and $v_2$. The other $S−2$ out of $N−2$ elements in $\{3,\dots, N\}$ are arbitrary, so $$\beta=2\binom{N-2}{S-2}=2\frac{S(S-1)}{N(N-1)}\binom{N}{S}=2\frac{\binom{S}{2}}{\binom{N}{2}}\binom{N}{S}.$$ And indeed, you can check that the number of terms in the sum is
$$\alpha N+\beta\binom{N}{2}=N\binom{N-1}{S-1}+N(N−1)\binom{N-2}{S-2}=(S+S(S−1))\binom{N}{S}=S^2\binom{N}{S},$$ which is as expected, since every summand in $$\sum_{\substack{A\subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}\\|A|=S}}{\left(\sum_{j\in A}v_j\right)^2}$$ contains $\binom{N}{S}$ squares of sums of $S$ summands each.